# Asymptotic for Bessel Function

Tags: special-functions

We have that, 
$$J_p(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sin \left( x - \frac{p\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \frac{r_p(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}$$
We also know that there exists $M>0$ such that $|r_p(x)| \leq M$.

I am curious, can you tell me an estimate for $M$? You do not have to derive it, just as reference, or a link, with a bound on this $M$.

Comment: See http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17#E3 and error bounds below.

Comment: I do not see it. They do not have the asymptotic formula I posted above there, not do they say what $M$ is.

Comment: Your formula corresponds to taking the very first term in their expansion (their $\omega$ differs from the argument of your sine function by $\pi/2$, which transform the sine into cosine).